# Problems with piecewise function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, piecewise

I'm trying to use a soliton plus a step for my initial condition for KdV equation, however the Heaviside function I use as a step is producing oscillations. I want to replace Heaviside function in my code with tanh(x/epsilon), but I get an error in Matlab saying 'Data must be numeric, datetime, duration or an array convertible to double.' at the following line:

figure(1); plot(x,u,'r.'); pause(1);

It's probably a straightforward fix but I can't seem to figure it out.
Please find the sample of my code below for reference.

```
close all
clear all
x = linspace(-20,20,401); 
N=401;
h=x(2)-x(1); % grid size
dt=0.0005;
%Soliton initial condition
Am=8; %Amplitude
mu=sqrt(Am/2);
x0=-15;
eps=0.0005;
c=1;
syms y
H(y)=piecewise(y < 0,0,y > 0,tanh(y/eps));
u= Am*(sech(mu*(x'))).^2+c^2*H(x)';
u1=u;
figure(1); plot(x,u,'r.'); pause(1);
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried to debug your code? Have you checked the variable `u`, of which type is it? Please read [how-to-debug-small-programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Irreducible variable `u`  is of the type `sym` and so is `H(y)`, this is the problem. But I didn't find helpful resources on how to define piecewise function differently.